# Скрыть блок по клику в не его области

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть кнопка:

```
<a class="services">Сервисы</a>
```

И блок

```
<div class="services__block" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Нужно сделать так что бы, при клике по кнопке блок появлялся, при повторном клике блок появляется (toggle) этот момент получилось реализовать, но еще нужно что бы при клике вне области блока этот блок исчезал, то же получилось:

```
<script>
  $(".services").click(function(){
    $(".services__block").toggle(200);
    $(this).toggleClass("services-red");
  });
  $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $(".services__block");
    var container2 = $(".services");
    if(container.has(e.target).length === 0 && container2.has(e.target).length === 0){
      container.hide();
      $(".services").removeClass("services-red");
    }
  });
</script>
```

Проблема в том что при клике по кнопке блок исчезает и появляется сразу, а нужно что бы он исчезал... Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Надеюсь вам нужен был такой вариант:

```js
$('.services').click(function() {
  $('.services__block').toggle(200);
  $(this).toggleClass('services-red');
  return false;
});
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  let el = $('.services__block'),
      el2 = $('.services');
  if(!el.is(e.target) && !el2.is(e.target) && el.has(e.target).length === 0) { // Выполняем функцию, если нажатый элемент НЕ el и НЕ el2 и данный элемент НЕ дочерний el
    el.hide(200, function(){
      el2.removeClass('services-red');
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.services-red {
  color: red;
}

.services__block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="services">Сервисы</a>
<div class="services__block" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Повесьте на document   событие клика которое скрывает блок, а на событии клика по .services добавьте e.stopPropagation(), это запретит всплытие что бы не отрабатывал клик по document

```
        $(".services").on('click', function(e){
            $(".services__block").toggle(200);
            $(this).toggleClass("services-red");
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
        $(document).on('click', function (e) {
            var container = $(".services__block");
            container.hide();
            $(".services").removeClass("services-red");
        });
```